# How to make ids of HTML elements unique so that something could be appended in the correct element on ajax response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Jquery is being used on rails views. Here a code sample:

```
<div id="comments" class="comments">
  <%= render :partial => 'comment', :collection => @comments %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#new_comment').bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
     $('#comments').append('<div class="comment-item">' + data.text + '</div>');
  });
});  
</script>
```

I have a form that sends an ajax request and on response the javascript function is called. I have multiple places in the page with this pattern and its dynamic. I need to make the id of div unique on append the response in correct id. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you can use [`content_tag_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag_for) or [`div_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper.html#method-i-div_for) helpers to get a class

```
<%= div_for @post do %>
  <!-- stuff -->
<% end %>
```

Which is the same as:

```
<%= content_tag_for :div, @post do %>
  <!-- stuff -->
<% end %>
```

Will result in something like:

```
<div class="posts" id="post_42">
  <!-- stuff -->
</div>
```

In HAML, you can use the square brackets to achieve the same:

```
%div[@post]
  / stuff
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out these functions call "dom_id" and "dom_class", if you just want the class and id strings by themselves.